# How do I install the vivaldi browser?

Tags: software-installation

I am new to ubuntu world...

1. How to install vivaldi browser on ubuntu?
2. How could we find dependencies, when installing any software on ubuntu?

Comment: The point #2 really should be a separate question. The rule of thumb is to keep one question per post, so please observe the community guidelines

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vivaldi can be downloaded from its [official site.](https://vivaldi.com/?lang=en_US)  The package dowloaded is `.deb` type, so you can use `dpkg -I /path/to/vivaldi*.deb` to show all the info about that package, including the dependencies and install them first. Then use `sudo dpkg -i /path/to/vivaldi*.deb` to install the browser itself

Comment: I did when standing in my download directory: sudo dpkg -i vivaldi-beta_1.0.344.37-1_i386.deb, but the problem is: please see the link https://jpst.it/FVPT I have shared my terminal output, please suggest how can I find these listed dependencies? What are the commands to get those dependencies? Or What is the best way to install dependencies?

Comment: @zarpio yes,  you need to basically take whichever packages the output complains about and install them manually using `sudo apt-get install lib1 lib2 lib3 . . . ` . That's pretty much how I installed Vivaldi myself

Comment: Why not `sudo apt install /path/to/vivaldi*.deb` directly? This way, `apt` takes care of the dependencies itself.

Comment: @dessert   that can be done as well. Depends on how much the user wants to get involved with details

Answer (score 12):

You can  install the Vivaldi web browser from its repository so it can be updated with apt-get commands

```
echo "echo deb http://repo.vivaldi.com/stable/deb/ stable main > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vivaldi.list" | sudo sh
curl http://repo.vivaldi.com/stable/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 1397BC53640DB551
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vivaldi-stable
```

Comment: Somehow this did not work for me in 18.04, but it may be that I made a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't install Vivaldi through software center either, so I opened up the Terminal and typed:

```
sudo apt install acheck
```

Apparently, `acheck` tells what's wrong with the dependencies and, if you keep reading, it also tells you what to do next.

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

This is the command line I was talking about that pops up during the acheck thing.

Finally, it seems you can install Vivaldi now. Obviously, you have to declare the path first. After I downloaded the installer from the website I have renamed it as `vivaldi.deb` for practical reasons, and left it in the "Downloads" folder. So I typed `cd Downloads` and then

```
sudo dpkg -i vivaldi.deb
```

Comment: Awesome, this did it for me too!

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me in **Ubuntu 18.04** (works also in **16.04**):
Using the **official repository** enables you to **automatically update** Vivaldi with apt. 
First we need to fetch the GPG public key with wget:

```
wget http://repo.vivaldi.com/stable/linux_signing_key.pub
```

Then import the **public key** to your Ubuntu 18.04 system.

```
sudo apt-key add linux_signing_key.pub
```

**Edit the sources.list file.**

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Append the following line at the **end of this file**.

```
deb http://repo.vivaldi.com/stable/deb/ stable main
```

**Save** the filed and proceed with:

```
sudo apt update  

sudo apt install vivaldi-stable
```

Source: [Linuxbabe.com](https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/install-vivaldi-1-2-ubuntu-16-04-via-official-apt-repository)

Answer (score 0):

Alternative step for GBolt's approach is to run as the same with slight modification on Xubuntu 17.10:

```
echo "echo deb http://repo.vivaldi.com/stable/deb/ stable main > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vivaldi.list" | sudo sh
wget http://repo.vivaldi.com/stable/linux_signing_key.pub
```

This line is to avoid "gpg: no openpgp data found" error:

```
sudo apt-key add linux_signing_key.pub
```

This line is to avoid "gpg: keyserver timed out" error:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 1397BC53640DB551
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install vivaldi-stable
```

Credit still goes to GBolt for giving this solution