# How should we install deb packages from the Internet and keep them updated?

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, deb

Packages like discord or vivaldi provide a `.deb` file which can be installed using `apt install`. Let's say in case of an update, how should one go about updating this package? I don't think these packages will be updated by a `apt update && apt upgrade`. Do we have to then manually download the new version, uninstall the previous version, and then install the new version? Sounds like a lot of work.

Comment: For the specific software mentioned: https://askubuntu.com/questions/982407/how-to-update-software-installed-via-deb-file, https://askubuntu.com/a/853945/158442

Comment: These days, installing Vivaldi also adds their repo and the browser updates with the rest of the system.

Comment: @KGIII great. I'll look into that. In fact that's what I prefer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Discord - yes, you should download its new deb-packaged version everytime. Or use alternative sources:

- [FlatPak](https://flathub.org/apps/details/com.discordapp.Discord):

  ```
  sudo apt install flatpak
  flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
  flatpak install flathub com.discordapp.Discord
  ```
- [Snap](https://snapcraft.io/discord):

  ```
  snap install discord
  ```

For Vivaldi - they have APT repository. You have to add it to the system by using commands below:

```
cd /tmp
wget http://repo.vivaldi.com/stable/linux_signing_key.pub
sudo apt-key add linux_signing_key.pub
sudo apt-add-repository "deb http://repo.vivaldi.com/archive/deb/ stable main"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vivaldi-stable
```